# Download files to specific path with CHEF

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

How can you download files and specify the path with CHEF?
I looked into the documentation and found remote_file ressource but i couldnt manage to download a file to a specific path.

My Attempt was this but somehow i couldnt figure the exact syntax out

```
remote_file 'E:\\' do
   source 'https://bintray.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go/jfrog-cli-windows-amd64/1.19.0'
   show_progress true
   action :create_if_missing
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a direct URL to the file and you should use `/` instead of `\\`, this should work fine:

```
remote_file 'E:/jfrog.exe' do
   checksum      "3ddb79b932b34b57a29326a488dcb629049f48277c1568f2d03048cafae38191"
   source        "https://bintray.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go/download_file?file_path=1.19.0/jfrog-cli-windows-amd64/jfrog.exe"
   show_progress true
   action        :create_if_missing
end
```

I have added a checksum, as a 'good practice'.

Comment: Thanks i will look into it. To the checksum , what is the best way to create a checksum so i can set it appropriately.

Comment: It is sha256 of the file, on linux you need `sha256sum` binary, checksum can be generated with `sha256sum <path to the file>`. However, I have took this checksum from bintray page, many package maintainers provide checksums in various 'formats'.

Comment: You don't generally need to set `checksum` on a `remote_file` anymore. We handle the two most common caching systems by default for you.

Comment: In my case it is not about caching, I want to be sure file wasn't altered.